# iOS 8 Mapkit and Location - Are there any restriction to number of requests per day?

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, mapkit

As the title says, apple doesn't provide any explicit answer to that question. I don't want to use google api because of it's request's limitation and I wonder if MapKit in iOS 8 got any? (so far there were no such limitations, but with each release of iOS things may change).

If there's no such limits, what are the drawbacks of using MapKit in iOS8 release? Are there any cases when Google Maps API become more helpful?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html

Look for the part - Getting General-Purpose Directions Information

"There are no request limits per app or developer ID, so well-written apps that operate correctly should experience no problems. However, throttling may occur in a poorly written app that creates an extremely large number of requests"

Comment: @AzzaFazza3515, +1 for the link.

Comment: I get error code 4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926164/mkerrordomain-error-4-iphone.
It occurs in 1/3 searches, when using queries that results in places, in the same location. 
A search like *pizza* will not always give results - despite being in the same location. So you sometimes get pizzerias and sometimes not - in the same location. And it happens that customers can't make a succefull search the first time they open the app. And it can be break the first search for me as well  when I have been away and not using the api for a day.

Answer (score 2):

The only limitation I'm familiar with is the reverse geocoding of coordinates via [`CLGeocoder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:) which says:

> Geocoding requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many requests in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail. When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder passes an error object with the value `kCLErrorNetwork` to your completion handler.

Unfortunately, I've never seen this limitation quantified.

Personally, I always assumed this was a caveat to prevent people from writing code that tried to abuse the API, using it to programmatically mine the geocode database by repeatedly reverse geocoding every point on a grid, or what have you. I've never run up against this limitation in standard user interaction with a map.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no limitation in Apple Maps requests. And the advantage with google maps Api is better map data.